# How do I get the following Grid Layout

Tags: css, layout, grid

I'm quite new to CSS Grid and I need to transform the following design into a Grid Layout. I already found solutions for equally sized widths but I found none for **dynamic heights** combined with differently sized widths. Does anyone has an idea how to solve this in a charming way?

[image: Layout]

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://medium.com/@andybarefoot/a-masonry-style-layout-using-css-grid-8c663d355ebb

Comment: Nah not really. I need to build it without any library. The examples in the article also covers equally sized boxes only.

Comment: Then you can read more about it here: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4650 It is not yet available in CSS grid. Still in development.